# Trouble with user defined data type in map

Tags: c++, maps, user-defined-types

Goal : Make a map of student registrations via the key, their student number.

Issue : Seems that for some reason when I go to add an object to my map the OS crashes my program.

Structure of my Registration object:

```
private:
std::string fName;         
std::string lName;          
long studentId;            
unsigned semester;          
Vector<Result> results;  //User defined data structure, tested and works
```

Map declaration:

```
std::map<long, Registration> studentRegistrations;
```

I use the studentId in the object as the key. So to test I created a Registration object, set it's studentId and then passed that to the following method in another class that basically encapsulates my map, called Registrar.

```
 void Registrar::setRegistration(Registration& regist)
{
    studentRegistrations[regist.GetStudentId()] = regist; //Crashes here
}
```

My main:

```
int main()
{
    Registration Regist;
    Registrar R;

    Regist.SetStudentId(200);
    R.setRegistration(Regist);
}
```

Program returns -1073741819 <0xC00000005> on windows. If that in anyway helps.

Comment: Does your `Vector` have a copy constructor? If not, you need one. If yes, have you tested it with an empty list?

Comment: All of the other members of Registration you show will copy into the map just fine. Quick experiment: What happens if you just make a `std::map<long, Vector<Result> >` and just work with adding `Vector<Result>`s?

Comment: Okay, so just realised that my Registration constructor doesn't allocate any memory for my Vector.

IE Constructor
`Registration::Registration()
{
    fName = "Not Set";
    lName = "Not Set";
    studentId = 0;
    semester = 0;
}`

Comment: Hmmm... same thing, so issue with my vector it seems...
Thanks btw @user4581301 :)

Does this mean it's my copy constructor in my Vector?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `Vector<Result> results` allocates the Vector, but I have no idea about the internals of the Vector. Right about now I should ask why not just use std::vector? School assignment?

Comment: Short answer yes. I had to use my own vector for assignment 1 and this is assignment two, where i can use STL Vector but TBH i'd pref to find the root of the problem and learn from the frustration.

I'd like to at the end have a Vector that I can reuse, and understand the concepts etc. (Also for BSTree, but not related to this- Learning data structures.)

Comment: Wait, I'm so sorry... I haven't got a copy constructor. Just overloaded the assignment operator.
Sorry, if I wasted anytime.